# Replace text, but keeping content in between

Tags: regex, text, latex

I have the following

```
\citep{lehrer1969, nonaka2000}, or \citep{nonaka2000}
```

and I would like to get a regex to wrap `\index{}` around the `\citep{..}`

resulting in

`\index{\citep{lehrer1969, nonaka2000}}` for example

what is the regex to do this safely please?

If it helps, this is in TexStudio

Comment: You can also do this straight from within LaTeX without using `regex`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find:

```
(\\citep\{[^{}]*\})
```

Replace with

```
\index{\1}
```

[See it in action by clicking here](https://regex101.com/r/qO5qH9/1)

---

The idea is:

- Characters that have special meaning like `\` or `{` need to be escaped with a slash
- `[^{}]*` - zero or more characters, which are not `{` or `}`
- `\1` references the first group of the match, which in this case is the entire match as we enclosed everything with `()`

Comment: Thanks, this worked almost perfectly apart from producing two \\ before index, it worked like a charm!

Comment: Yea ndn is rocking today ! :D